# Angulartics2 With Multiple Providers?

Tags: angular, typescript, angulartics2

Using Angulartics2 for Google Analytics and Piwik ( matomo ). If I use only one provider, they work great, but having syntax problem when trying to use both. In app.module.ts....

```
import {Angulartics2Module, Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics, Angulartics2Piwik} from 'angulartics2';
```

...and later for use in the module:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    StaticModule,
    Angulartics2Module.forRoot([ Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics, Angulartics2Piwik ]),
    MetaModule.forRoot(metaConfig)
],
declarations: [
    App
],
bootstrap: [ App ],
providers: [ ENV_PROVIDERS, APP_PROVIDERS ],
schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
....
```

In app.routes.ts, here is the main code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NoContent } from './no-content';
import { Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics } from 'angulartics2';
import { Angulartics2Piwik } from "angulartics2";

import { DataResolver } from './app.resolver';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
{ path: '', loadChildren: () => System.import('./home/home.module').then(mod => mod.HomeModule), pathMatch: 'full' },
{ ...other paths... },
{ path: '**', component: NoContent }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule
{
//  constructor(angulartics2GoogleAnalytics:       Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics) {}
constructor(angulartics2Piwik: Angulartics2Piwik) {}
}
```

I get a "multiple constructors not allowed" if I uncomment both of the constructors in the export class AppRoutingModule...

I want to ensure that I am using both providers, but can't seem to figure out how to get both in the export.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you need to inject services in AppRoutingModule. It should be done in component right?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the constructor from app.routing.module.ts which is not necessary,

```
constructor(angulartics2Piwik: Angulartics2Piwik) { //remove this
}
```

Comment: I need to use both Google Analytics and Piwik analytics. The code above has one commented-out because that works - I need both.

Comment: however you do not need to inject inside the constructor of the module. add it under providers of the parent module and use it in the component (inject there)

Comment: So, in the app.module I have it in the imports:


    Angulartics2Module.forRoot([ Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics, Angulartics2Piwik ]),

Is that what you mean?